# How do I find the circumsphere of any spatial geometry?

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry

How do I find the circumscribed sphere of any spatial geometry? I want to:

- automatically generate its circumscribed sphere in the original three-dimensional graphics,
- label its center position,
- label a representative sphere radius and
- generate an analytical equation for its circumscribed sphere.

If the solid shape does not have a circumscribed sphere, the algorithm should indicate this.

Below are two examples of such geometric shapes.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
d = {0, 0, 0};
b = {2, 0, 0};
c = {0, 2, 0};
e = Mean[{b, c}];
a = {x1, y1, z1};
a = SolveValues[{VectorAngle[a - d, b - d] == 60 Degree, 
    VectorAngle[a - d, c - d] == 60 Degree, Norm[a - d] == 2, 
    z1 > 0}, {x1, y1, z1}] // First
f = {x2, y2, z2};
f = SolveValues[{a - d == f - e, z2 > 0}, {x2, y2, z2}] // First
labels = {Text[Style[A, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a, {-1, -1}], 
   Text[Style[B, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b, {1, 1}], 
   Text[Style[C, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c, {1, 1}], 
   Text[Style[D, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d, {-2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[E, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], e, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[F, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], f, {-1, -2}]};
dashLines = {Dashed, 
   AbsoluteThickness[2], {Brown, Line[{{c, a}}]}, {Red, 
    Line[{{c, b}, {d, c}}]}, {Purple, Line[{{e, f}}]}, {Black, 
    Line[{{e, a}, {d, e}}]}};
realLines = {AbsoluteThickness[2], 
   Line[{{a, d}, {a, b}, {b, d}, {a, f}, {b, f}}]};
Show[Graphics3D[{dashLines, realLines, labels}, Boxed -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> {2, -3.5, 1.28}], 
 RegionPlot3D[Polygon[{a, b, d}], MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 + #3 &}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]], 
 RegionPlot3D[Polygon[{a, b, f}], MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 + #3 &}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]], 
 Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{d, d + {0, 0, 2}}, {b, b + {1, 0, 0}}, {c, 
      c + {0, 1, 0}}}], 
   Text[Style["z", Red, 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    d + {0, 0, 2}, {-1, -1}], 
   Text[Style["y", Red, 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    c + {0, 1, 0}, {-2, -1}], 
   Text[Style["x", Red, 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    b + {1, 0, 0}, {2, -1}]}]]
```

[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"];
c = {0, 0, 0};
d = {2, 0, 0};
b = {0, 2, 0};
a = b + d;
h = 2;
c1 = {0, 0, h};
d1 = d + c1
a1 = a + c1
b1 = b + c1
e = 1/2 (b1 + b)
f = 1/2 (b1 + c1)
labels = {Text[Style[A, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a, {-1, -1}], 
   Text[Style[B, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b, {1, 1}], 
   Text[Style[C, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c, {1, 1}], 
   Text[Style[D, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d, {-2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[A1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a1, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[B1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b1, {-1, -2}], 
   Text[Style[C1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c1, {0, 1}], 
   Text[Style[D1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d1, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[E, 12, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"], e, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[F, 12, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"], f, {3, 0}]};
dashLines = {Dashed, 
   AbsoluteThickness[2], {Red, Line[{{c, d}, {c1, c}, {c, b}}]}};
realLines = {AbsoluteThickness[2], 
   Line[{{a, d}, {a, b}, {a1, a}, {b, b1}, {a1, d1}, {a1, b1}, {c1, 
      d1}, {b1, c1}, {d, d1}}]};
Show[Graphics3D[{dashLines, realLines, labels}, Boxed -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> {2, 3.5, 1.28}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `Circumsphere`.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question. In particular, I am not sure what a "spatial geometry" is. However, have you seen [`BoundingRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundingRegion.html)? It has a `"MinBall"` option.

Comment: From [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_sphere#:~:text=The%20circumscribed%20sphere%20is%20the,lie%20on%20a%20common%20sphere.) `The circumscribed sphere is the three-dimensional analogue of the circumscribed circle. All regular polyhedra have circumscribed spheres, but most irregular polyhedra do not have one, since in general not all vertices lie on a common sphere.`

Comment: What  I mean is that `https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circumsphere.html` instead of changing the title.

Comment: @cvgmt ```Circumsphere[{a, b, c, d, a1, b1, c1, d1}]
Graphics3D[Circumsphere[{a, b, c, d, a1, b1, c1, d1}]]
```get the Sphere[{1, 1, 1}, Sqrt[3]],But the resulting graph is just a ball, without placing the original graph inside the ball. How can we obtain such a result graph?

Comment: ```Show[Graphics3D[{dashLines, realLines, labels}, 
  Graphics3D[Circumsphere[{a, b, c, d, a1, b1, c1, d1}]], 
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {2, 3.5, 1.28}]]```Why can't the original shape and the Circumsphere be drawn together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an example, I take your first example.

The "Show" produces a "Graphics3D" object. The points in this are packed into   "GraphicsComplex" objects. The points are the first elements in these objects. We may therefore get all points by:

```
pts = Flatten[Cases[gr, GraphicsComplex[x_, ___] -> x, Infinity], 1];
```

Now we take all pairs and calulate the distances. The larges distance will be a diameter of the searched for sphere. From the diameter, we get the center and radius of the sphere:

```
subs = Subsets[pts, {2}];
dias = (Norm[#[[1]] - #[[2]]]) & /@ subs;
max = Max[dias];
pos = PositionLargest[dias]
diam = Extract[subs, pos]
sphere = Ball[Plus @@ diam/2, Norm[Subtract @@ diam/2]]
```

Finally we may include the sphere in the original graphics:

```
Show[Graphics3D[{dashLines, realLines, labels}, Boxed -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> {2, -3.5, 1.28}], 
 RegionPlot3D[Polygon[{a, b, d}], MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 + #3 &}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]], 
 RegionPlot3D[Polygon[{a, b, f}], MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 + #3 &}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]], 
 Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{d, d + {0, 0, 2}}, {b, b + {1, 0, 0}}, {c, 
      c + {0, 1, 0}}}], 
   Text[Style["z", Red, 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    d + {0, 0, 2}, {-1, -1}], 
   Text[Style["y", Red, 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    c + {0, 1, 0}, {-2, -1}], 
   Text[Style["x", Red, 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    b + {1, 0, 0}, {2, -1}], Opacity[0.5], sphere}]]
```

[image]